# helm not found error when building custom image

Tags: kubernetes

I am using the below pipeline to pull an image from DockerHub which has helm command built in and create a pod out of it.  The idea is to use the helm command to deploy a NodeJS application.

However, when I ran the built, I got the below error saying helm is not found.  However, when I login to the pod and check, the command is there.  Appreciate if anyone can advise how to fix this false alarm.

Thanks.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
      label "helm-dev"
  }
  stages {
    stage('sleep') {
      steps {
        sh 'sleep 30'
      }
    }
    
    stage('helm list') {
      steps {
        sh 'helm list -n dev'
      }
    }
  }
}




Started by user ddl
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Agent helm-dev-vmgvb is provisioned from template helm-dev
---
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
metadata:
  labels:
    env: "dev"
    jenkins/label-digest: "e31eecd34464cad3915211d12188103378eff272"
    jenkins/label: "helm-dev"
  name: "helm-dev-vmgvb"
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - "999999"
    command:
    - "sleep"
    image: "dtzar/helm-kubectl"
    imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
    name: "helm-dev"
    resources:
      limits: {}
      requests: {}
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    tty: false
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
    workingDir: "/home/jenkins/agent"
  - env:
    - name: "JENKINS_SECRET"
      value: "********"
    - name: "JENKINS_TUNNEL"
      value: "jenkins-agent.jenkins.svc.cluster.local:50000"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_NAME"
      value: "helm-dev-vmgvb"
    - name: "JENKINS_NAME"
      value: "helm-dev-vmgvb"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR"
      value: "/home/jenkins/agent"
    - name: "JENKINS_URL"
      value: "http://jenkins.jenkins.svc.cluster.local:8080/"
    image: "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.11-1-jdk11"
    name: "jnlp"
    resources:
      limits: {}
      requests:
        memory: "256Mi"
        cpu: "100m"
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
  hostNetwork: false
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: "linux"
  restartPolicy: "Never"
  serviceAccountName: "svcdev"
  volumes:
  - emptyDir:
      medium: ""
    name: "workspace-volume"

Running on helm-dev-vmgvb in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/testpipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Run maven)
[Pipeline] sh
+ sleep 30
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (helm list)
[Pipeline] sh
+ helm list -n dev
/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/testpipeline@tmp/durable-b7cf28e8/script.sh: 1: helm: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE


➜  dev-webapps git:(main) ✗ kubectl get pod -A
NAMESPACE              NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
dev                    dev-mysqldb-0                               1/1     Running   10 (21h ago)    3d6h
dev                    helm-dev-vmgvb                              2/2     Running   0               4s
jenkins                jenkins-0                                   2/2     Running   44 (21h ago)    10d
kube-system            coredns-64897985d-nmdbh                     1/1     Running   23 (21h ago)    11d
kube-system            etcd-minikube                               1/1     Running   23 (21h ago)    11d
kube-system            kube-apiserver-minikube                     1/1     Running   23 (21h ago)    11d
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-minikube            1/1     Running   23 (21h ago)    11d
kube-system            kube-proxy-9ln7l                            1/1     Running   23 (21h ago)    11d
kube-system            kube-scheduler-minikube                     1/1     Running   23 (21h ago)    11d
kube-system            storage-provisioner                         1/1     Running   38 (122m ago)   11d
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-58549894f-vp9gb   1/1     Running   23 (21h ago)    11d
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-ccd587f44-cl46l        1/1     Running   32 (122m ago)   11d

➜  dev-webapps git:(main) ✗ kubectl -n dev exec -it helm-dev-vmgvb -- bash
Defaulted container "helm-dev" out of: helm-dev, jnlp


bash-5.1# helm list -n dev
NAME        NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART           APP VERSION
dev-mysqldb dev         1           2022-03-12 16:19:19.934457 +0800 +0800  deployed    mysql-8.8.26    8.0.28

bash-5.1# which helm
/usr/local/bin/helm
```

Comment: Hi Ldd welcome to SO. What happens when you change your Jenkinsfile to say `/usr/local/bin/helm` instead? I suspect it's just a `PATH` misunderstanding

Comment: Hi mdaniel, I did that but still hit the same error.

Comment: Then please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71484818/edit) and include the new, accurate, experiment along with its updated error message; we're not at your computer to know what you tried, and computers are _super picky_ about every single detail